# django-threadedcomments supported in django 1.2

Tags: django

Is django-threadedcomments 0.52 supported by django 1.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although an open bug report isn't a sure-fire answer, [it doesn't look like it works](http://code.google.com/p/django-threadedcomments/issues/detail?id=57&q=1.2) with 1.2 as standard, but there is a hack to potentially fix it (see the ticket, linked)

Comment: There are still some issues around CSRF though

Comment: Damn. I did say 'potentially' though ;o) If it's the missing {% crsf_token %}, I think there are some fixes around for injecting the CSRF token into the threadedcomments template tags, or you can manually hack them, perhaps.